# Check all tables that have a column called

Tags: h2

In H2 I can see all tables by doing:

```
select * from informationschema.tables
```

How do I check what tables have a column called: `amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='AMOUNT'
```

You might want to have the name of table schema as well:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='AMOUNT'
```